# Get list of new and removed files from git

Tags: git

How do I get a list of files that have been removed or added?  I'd like to compare my current branch against the version of the files in origin's master to see what's new.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff ..origin/master --summary | grep "create" | awk '{ print $4 }'
git diff ..origin/master --summary | grep "delete" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

`git ls-files` may also be useful.